# Simple validation using JUnit and Hamcrest

Tags: java, junit5, hamcrest

I have a map which contains child IDs (childid1, childid2, childid3) and status mapping and I have a list having all the IDs (say childid1, childid2, childid3 etc)

All these childids are mapped to a single parent ID say PID and PID also has some status. When I change status of PID say from A to B then based on condition, status of childids changes like A to B and B remains B and status C remains C.

When I change status of PID say from B to C then based on conditions status of childids changes like A to C and B remains B and status C remains C.

Without writing any complex logic, is there any simple way of validating this using JUnit 5 and Hamcrest. Something like:

```
if(updateStatus.equals("A")){
            assertAll("",
                    () -> {
                        childIds.stream().forEach(id -> {
                            assertThat("", idStatusMap.get(id).equals("A"), is("B"));
                            assertThat("", idStatusMap.get(id).equals("B"), is("B"));
                            assertThat("", idStatusMap.get(id).equals("C"), is("B"));
                        });
                    });
        }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your logic/control workflow for changing the child Ids. But, I reckon, something like this should work:

```java
if (updateStatus.equals("A") {
  Optional<> result = childIds.stream()
    .filter(id -> idStatusMap.get(id).equals("A") && id.equals("B"))
    .filter(id -> idStatusMap.get(id).equals("B") && id.equals("B"))
    .filter(id -> idStatusMap.get(id).equals("C") && id.equals("B"))
    .findAny();

  assertTrue(result.isPresent());
}
```